# Error on refresh using multiselect.js

Tags: jquery, refresh, multi-select

I'm using the excellent multiselect jQuery plugin available at http://loudev.com/

I have it working except that when I try to use the refresh method as in:

```
$('#FPCountry').multiSelect('refresh');
```

I get an error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

I've initialized the multiselect box on the page load.  Can anyone provide pointers as to why the refresh is failing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need first `$('#FPCountry').multiSelect();`